# How to make chrome to force reload JS from my web server?

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, caching

I have a PHP website with lot of JS and CSS files included with the  tag. The problem is whenever I update any JS or CSS and then open my website, chrome is still loading old versions of the JS,CSS . I know client side we can force refresh by Ctrl+Shift+R , but it's too tough to instruct my website users to do this every single time.

I have tried these but still no luck. So please suggest a way to force the browser to reload JS from my server every time instead of cache.

```html
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"> <!-- tells browser not to cache -->
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"> <!-- says that the cache expires 'now' -->
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"> <!-- says not to use cached stuff, if there is any -->
```

Comment: _"The problem is whenever I update any JS or CSS and then open my website, chrome is still loading old versions of the JS,CSS"_ Do you mean when JavaScript and CSS are updated at server?

Comment: Simply configure your server to send the correct cache control headers.  What server are you using?

Comment: I am using a PHP website hosted in azure cloud.

Comment: @guest271314 yes when i update the JS, CSS in my server website code

Comment: @RangarajanK Have you tried the approaches at linked Question?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: tried.. still not working

Answer (score 0):

add a version id like this, example.com/js/example.js?$versionid,if you do this for debug,you can disable chrome cache in developer tools

Comment: can you explain a bit more ? my JS file don't have any versions. so what version id should I give

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I'll elaborate for anyone reading. By putting a query string with any random value (not necessarily a version number), the browser will treat the file you're loading like it's a new file. That's why this works.